# Adding scrollviewr to ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm struggling with my XAML! I have 3 rows, and they don't really change height on the page, other than the middle row. The middle row has a ListBox.

Depending on the size of the screen I would like the 2nd row's height to get bigger as items are added to the ListBox unless it pushes the 3rd row out of the screen. In this case, I'd like the ListBox to show a Scrollbar. I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

My research shows for Height we have Auto and * - the Auto will size based upon the control, and the * will fill the entire gap. I can't see how either of these fit what I need really...

The following is code from a UserControl. This UserControl is rendered in the parents TabControl.

My effort is

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
               <TextBlock Text="[?] Source directory" />
         </StackPanel>

        <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}"  Grid.Row="1" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        //data template code
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
                    <Button Content="Save" />
            </StackPanel>

     </Grid>
```

**Edit**

If I set a height on the grid, it works, but, setting a fixed height is not an option as it won't scale for any resolution.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start

Comment: So do you want those two StackPanels docked to the top and bottom, while allowing the ListView to take up the entire middle portion of the screen?

Comment: @estebro that is correct

Comment: You're missing a part somewhere I think, you end your Grid right after your StackPanel at the top, so those RowDefinitions aren't valid for where your ListView sits.

Comment: @ChrisW., sorry, that was my typo. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbar won't show up because it doesn't know the `Height` of the parent which is the `Grid` and because the `RowDefinitions` are defined as `Auto` and `*`.

If you want the Scrollbar to show up you have to explicitly set a height in the `Grid`

```
<Grid Height="700">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
           <TextBlock Text="[?] Source directory" />
     </StackPanel>

    <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}"  Grid.Row="1" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    //data template code
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
        <Button Content="Save" />
     </StackPanel>

 </Grid>
```

Comment: Whilst the code you provide works, the problem is, it needs to scale for different screen resolutions. Whilst a height of 700 is fine for 1024*768, it's not if some one had 800*600, nor if some one has a much higher resolution. Is there really no way to make this dynamic?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions If you want it to scale for different resolutions then you would have to compute how much height you want the `Grid` to have and set it. You can use a create an attach property and set the computed height value. Alternatively, you can try using `ViewBox` inside but I forgot if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

You could use a [DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) layout with its attribute `LastChildFill=True`. You would then need to also add the attribute `DockPanel.Dock`=[LOCATION] to each of your elements (StackPanels and ListView). Since you want the ListView to take up the remaining space, just make sure to have that as the last child inside your `<DockPanel>`.

Comment: Interesting, let me try it

Comment: Sounds good. Just tag me in your comments if you need some help.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I've tried. The only way to get it to work is, as per III post, is to set a height for the control. The problem is, this means it won't scale with different resolutions

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Did you get rid of your grid? And how are you using this where you don't know the height?

Comment: It's a UserControl, shown in a TabControl. Yes, I totally removed the `Grid`